# how to trigger popads on click on the specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, ads

I have integrated popads to my site. it is working fine but the problem is that it triggers everywhere on the page. The thing I want is that when the user click on the certain div then popads should trigger but it is not working.

Here is my code.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#player_embed").click(function(){
    alert('aaa');

   var pa = document.createElement('script'); pa.type = 'text/javascript'; pa.async = true;
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
      pa.src = '//c1.popads.net/pop.js';
      pa.onerror = function() {
        var sa = document.createElement('script'); sa.type = 'text/javascript'; sa.async = true;
        sa.src = '//c2.popads.net/pop.js';
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(sa, s);
      };
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(pa, s);


});

});
```

Comment: You likely will have an issue with the TOS: _Tomksoft ad codes may not be modified from its original format without prior written consent from Tomksoft. Affiliate agrees to use the ad code provided by Tomksoft not more than once per page view._

Answer (score 0):

I think that you do not handle the click. You can try with `.on` trigger function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
  $("#player_embed").on('click',function(){
    alert('aaa');
    //your code
  });
});
```

Comment: @C.Fasolin.What is your answer? you had just copy paste my code again and even this copy paste code has syntax error.

Comment: @C.Fasolin,What are you doing.Just copy paste my code again and again.where is your solution?

Comment: I change your 'click' event handler into 'on' event handler, now I suppose the div with id equal "player_embed" is the div that you would display  popads

Comment: try using `one` instead since you now add the script every time you click

Comment: @mplungjan, the click event is triggered on div click but the add not show. When I put the add without click function it works fine.Do you have any expereince of working with popads?

Comment: @C.Fasolin buddy what you say about ads? it is not about click event triggering.

Comment: @mplungjan any solution?

Comment: the snipped of code about ads i think that include once on load on page not on click event

Comment: @C.Fasolin but I need to show it on click on "embed_player" . Is there any way?

Comment: popads has a restapi to call now I not remember wich api you can call, i suppose that explain in api reference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148729/discussion-between-dev-and-c-fasolin).